# Is it possible for `lapply` to return partial processing results under a "timeout" constraint?

Tags: r, timeout, lapply

I have some code that takes a long time to execute. I am therefore using `R.util`'s `withTimeout`. The synthax goes like this:

```
res <- withTimeout({
  v1 %>% mutate(Output = unlist(lapply(as.list(data.frame(t(v1))),function(x) 
  SomeFunction(x))))
}, timeout = 2, onTimeout = "warning")
```

In my code, `v1` is a data frame with many rows, and the function works row-wise (using `lapply`). I am allowing the function to run for 2 seconds, and if it takes longer it outputs a warning. However, the output already accomplished seems to have not been saved anywhere! How do I change the code such that the output itself will be returned as well as the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity I tried the following, and it seems to work well.

```
## an example data frame of 1000 columns
## `lapply` will loop a function over it column by column
x <- data.frame(matrix(sample.int(2, 2 * 1000, TRUE), 2, 1000))

## actually a wrapper function of your `SomeFunction`
## it takes an additional `time_limit` (in seconds)
## is also access a GLOBAL variable `elapsed_time`
f <- function (x, time_limit) {
  if (elapsed_time < time_limit) {
    t1 <- proc.time()[[3]]
    z <- tabulate(sample(x, 1e+5, TRUE))  ## an arbitrary example function here
    t2 <- proc.time()[[3]]
    elapsed_time <<- elapsed_time + (t2 - t1)  ## note the `<<-`
    } else {
    z <- NULL
    }
  z
  }

elapsed_time <- 0                  ## elapsed time counter (in global environment)
oo <- lapply(x, f, time_limit = 2) ## 2 seconds time limit

elapsed_time
#[1] 2.002

sum(sapply(oo, is.null))
#[1] 693
```

So on my laptop, the iteration terminates after (1000 - 693) = 307 rounds. `lapply` still returns a length 1000 list, but only the first 307 elements hold the processing result, while the remaining 693 entries are `NULL`.

Actually, this serves a good example where `<<-` would be useful.